# How to resolve unexpected response code: 400 in dropbox API

Tags: java, dropbox-api

I'm using the `dropbox-core-sdk-1.7.7.jar` and I have an access token.

But it's showing the below error:

> Exception in thread "main" com.dropbox.core.DbxException$BadResponse:
>   unexpected response code: 400

Comment: A response code of 400 means "user error," but the response code isn't enough information to determine specifically what's wrong. Catch the exception and log `exception.getLocalizedMessage()` for more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Andrew noted, you should print out the error message for more information.

Based on the information you provided though, the issue is probably just that the SDK you're using is old and is using [the now retired API v1](https://blogs.dropbox.com/developers/2016/06/api-v1-deprecated/).

You should instead use the latest version of [the Dropbox Java SDK](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-java).